# if $\mathrm{rank}(A)=m$ and $\mathrm{rank}(B)=n$, is that true that $\mathrm{rank}(A\otimes B)$ equal to $\mathrm{rank}(A)*\mathrm{rank}(B)$?

Tags: tensor-rank

Please help me...
if I have $A,B$ are matrices and $\mathrm{rank}(A)=m$ and $\mathrm{rank}(B)=n$, is that true that $\mathrm{rank} (A\otimes B)$ equal to $\mathrm{rank}(A) * \mathrm{rank}(B)$?
if false, what the true about $\mathrm{rank}(A\otimes B)$?
thx a lot.

Comment: Are you asking about the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of two matrices?

Comment: What was the point of introducing $m$ and $n$??

Comment: This property can be deduced from the more general statement that the eigenvalues of the product are all values $\lambda \cdot \mu$ with $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$ and $\mu$ an eigenvalue of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true. Using the fact that
$$
A\otimes B \cdot C\otimes D = AC \otimes BD
$$
we can use row and column operations to put $A\otimes B$ into a convenient diagonal form.

Comment: thx Yan Shuo Tan (y)